# How do make clean urls in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to make the urls for nginx (Ubuntu 14.04) clean, instead of example.com/profile.php it would be example.com/profile, or example.com/about.html to example.com/about

I have tried pretty much all the other ones on stackoverflow however they do not work, including making the site have a 500 internal server error, to making me download the PHP file

Current config

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

server_name mydomain.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}

server {
listen 80;
server_name mydomain.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443;
server_name api.mydomain.com;
 location / {
            proxy_pass https://mydomain:1337;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 150;
            proxy_send_timeout 100;
            proxy_read_timeout 100;
            proxy_buffers 4 32k;
            client_max_body_size 8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}
server {
listen 1337 ssl;
server_name api.mydomain.com;

root /usr/share/nginx/api;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `try_files` [1] directive.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri.php $uri.html =404;
}
```

In this example, if the browser was requesting `/folder/file`, it would first try to find `file.php` and then `file.html` before giving up and throwing a 404 error.

If that doesn't work, you can use an if statement instead:

```
location / {
    if (-f $request_filename.php) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php;
        break;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.html;
        break;
    }
}
```

1. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: tried both, it attempted to downlaod the pages instead of removing the extension

Comment: opps, misspelled, *download

Comment: Do you have the appropriate MIME type handlers for .html and .php? In the `location` block, try adding `default_type text/html;` as the first statement. (Actually, maybe try that in the `server` block...)